# In meteor how to verify user password before running a method?

Tags: meteor

I have a user profile page where I let the user edit his details. Before the user save these details, I need to ask for the user's password and verify it. How can I do this? The only method I use password for is the login method.

How can we verify the logged in user's password?

Comment: Why not just force login again with `Meteor.loginWithPassword()`? That will do the verification for you and log them out if they fail.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Thats also good but what if the user just mistype the password? Then he have to login again, go back to the profile page (profile data won't load if the user is loggedout) and do everything from the beginning. Won't be good for the user experience right?